# latest receipt info vs receipt in app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase

Now I am develop in app purchase in flutter, after I send a verify request, the response body of json contains last receipt info and receipt, I found the fields of last receipt info and receipt are different. which one should I store in database on my server? should I store both of them? should I merge the latest receipt info and receipt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the last `last_receipt_info` (they are not ordered, so sort by `purchase_date_ms` before) AND the `pending_renewal_info` matching your purchase (necessary for managing **grace periods**).

IAP is hard and since you're asking for something somewhat basic, I would recommend to read (a lot ?) of articles about IAP on iOS.

One more bit of advice: Apple is going to release **StoreKit 2**, which will change the way things are working. So if I were you, I would definitely look into this if you're only beginning implementing IAP in your app.

Here is the [official video about StoreKit 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10114/).

Comment: do you know how to get the product type(Subscription or consumable) in the client side? @romainsalles or I have to store a product list in the sever side?

Comment: I've not worked on the client side, only the server one... So I don't know :/

Comment: I add a product list table on the server side, and store the purchase type, when client send a verify request, I search the product by product id and get data subscribe type purchase from latest receipt info and consumable purchase from receipt in app field.@romainsalles

Comment: I add a product list table on the server side, and store the purchase type, when client send a verify request, I search the product by product id and get data subscribe type purchase from latest receipt info and consumable purchase from receipt in app field.@romainsalles

Comment: could you help me to see this problem?  please, I am confusing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165228/why-could-not-find-transaction-record-on-the-server-side-in-apple-app-purchase @romainsalles

Comment: how to know the user cancel subscribed? what I am doing now is to store the product id and expire date in the user table, and check peroid. But the last step I want to post a verify request and get cancelled date to recheck the user cancelled subscribed. should I store the latest receipt info into pay transaction record(this record is come from latest receipt info)? @romainsalles I could not find any document to guide how to handle this logic.

Comment: You're lucky, I've just written an article on the subject a few days ago: https://www.purchasely.com/blog/how-to-detect-an-expired-subscription-on-the-different-app-stores

Comment: Thank you. I think I know what should I do now.@romainsalles